# Как сделать чтобы при каждом вызове rand() выдавалось другое число. C++

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

Я не давно начал изучать С++. У меня всё было хорошо пока я не наткнулся на проблему, которая описана в заголовке этого вопроса. Я использовал **srand(time(NULL))**, но он не помог, а другого ответа в инете я не нашёл.
Код:

```
#include <iostream>//базовое
#include <stdlib.h>/*что-то страшное и непонятное, которое походу добавляет NULL */
#include <unistd.h>// time
#include <ctime>// random
using namespace std;
int e = 0;// счётчик ходов
int c = 1;// ответ на ''будешь ещё играть''
int b;// вводимое число
void ds(){
  cin >> b;
  e += 1;
  cout<<e;
}
void ssd(){
  cout<<"Введи число, которое по твоему мнению я загадал.(0-100)";
}
int main() {
  srand(time(NULL));
  int a = rand() % 100 + 1;
  ssd();
  ds();
  while(c == 1){
    if(b == a){
      cout<<"Ты угадал! Читер!\n";
      sleep(3);
      cout<<"Ещё? (1 - Да)(2 - Нет)\n";
      cin >> c;
      if(c==1){
        e = 0;
        int a = rand() % 100 + 1;
        ssd();
        ds();
      }
    }
    if(b != a){
      if(b < a){
        cout<<"Твоё число меньше моего. Попробуй ещё\n";
        ssd();
        ds();
      }
      if(b > a) {
        cout<<"Твоё число больше моего. Попробуй ещё\n";
        ssd();
        ds();
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Прочесть документацию по srand!

Comment: Если я правильно понял, тебе нужно, чтобы числа не повторялись. Первое что пришло в голову, создать битовый массив размером с диапазон значений. Это может быть дорого по памяти, в зависимости от диапазона...

Comment: Зачем вы исправили код в вопросе? Несмотря на один единственный вызов `srand(time(NULL))` в начале `main`, функция `rand()` продолжает генерировать одно и то же число/последовательность или что? В чем теперь заключается ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

функция srand(time(NULL)); должна вызываться один раз в Вашем приложении. Всего один раз.